# Put markers or layers on tags in OSM

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to use openstreetmap to put a marker or zone an area with an overlay for certain locations like farmland or commercial buildings.

Is it possible to do a custom map, where I pan around and put a marker, or an area overlay on these specific places?

Looking at the official openstreetmap client I see now way of exposing this information.

For a farmland I want to add a farm building marker, and for a commercial building a commercial marker for example.

Comment: Did you already take a look at [uMap](http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/)?

Comment: Unless you mean just the website "www.openstreetmap.org", there is no "official openstreetmap client".  There are 1001 examples and apps using OSM data, but none of them are "official".